# iPhone store user login info

Tags: ios, ios4

I want to store user info like username, id, email, password, phone and etc. Now I use `NSUserDefaults` to store info and I wonder if this is good way. If this is not good how should I store this info. Thanks in advance

Comment: Same question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/5210611/21052